# How to change the Select2 plugin behaviour from showing results on onclick to show results only on typing?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

How to change the Select2 plugin behaviour from showing results on onclick to show results only on typing?
 My requirement is normaly select2 show results on onclicking on the field , but i want to show results show only on typing any letter.

Comment: Try use `onkeyup` instead of onclick

Comment: But there is no onclick function  in the select2 4.0.3 .

Comment: As per your requirement you did not requrie an auto select plugin instead you require an auto complete plugin. Look out for http://easyautocomplete.com/ or search some other autocomplete plugins.